# Question about linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra

If S is a set of k independent vectors in V , then each vector in V can be expressed uniquely as a linear combination of vectors in S?

A independent set of vectors means the linear combination equalling zero means the scalars must be 0 right? Does this mean that of a vector in set can't be a linear combination of the other vectors?

Comment: That's almost correct. If $S$ is a set of $k$ independent vectors and $V$ is $k$ dimensional, $S$ will span all of $V$.

Comment: The now deleted answer from "Henry W." correctly answered the second question (but didn't address the first).  I'd have up-voted it but added a caveat in a comment if it hadn't been deleted.

Comment: The tag ([tag:independence]) is for question about independent events in probability theory, set the [tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/independence/info).

Answer (score 2):

> If S is a set of k independent vectors in V , then each vector in V can be expressed uniquely as a linear combination of vectors in S?

**No.**  **Uniqueness** is correct; **existence** is **not**.  For example, $\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0)\}$ in a linearly independent set and $(0,0,1)$ cannot be expressed as a linear combination of members of that set.

However, linear independence does imply that for those vectors that *can* be so expressed, the expression is **unique**.

> Does this mean that of a vector in set can't be a linear combination of the other vectors?

**Yes.** If $v_1$ is a linear combination of $v_2,\ldots,v_n$ then
$$
v_1 = c_2 v_2 + \cdots + c_n v_n \text{ for some scalars }c_1,\ldots,c_n.
$$
Therefore
$$
v_1 - c_2 v_2 - \cdots - c_n v_n = 0,
$$
and the coefficients are not all $0$ since the coefficient of $v_1$ is $1$.

Comment: So a vector can't be linear combination of the others because then it won't be linearly independent correct?

Comment: "it" won't be linearly independent... More specifically if $v_1$ is a linear combination of the others then adding $v_1$ to the set containing the others gives you a set that is not linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

If the dimension of the vector space $V$ over a field $F$ is $k$ then any linearly independent set $S$ of $k$ vectors will be a basis for $V$. This is the same as saying that for all $v \in V$ the vector $v$ has a unique representation as 
$$v= \sum_{i}c_is_i$$
where $c_i \in F$ and $s_i \in S$.

Since $0= \sum_{i}0s_i$, by uniqueness if we have a linear combination of linearly independent vectors equalling zero, then all the scalars must be zero. However, just because a set is linearly independent does not mean it spans the space $V$, for this we require that the set $S$ be linearly independent and have cardinality equal to that of the dimension of $V$.